# Char array printing random characters

Tags: java, arrays, char

I'm really struggling to print an array with random letters. If anybody could help me that would be great :)

```
public class CharFilter 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    int rows = 10;
    int cols = 10;
    char grid[][] = new char [rows][cols];

    for(int i=0; i<grid.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<grid[i].length;j++)
        {
            grid[i][j] = (char) (Math.random()*'a')+'b';

            String gprint = "";

            gprint = gprint + String.format("%2c", grid[i][j]);

            System.out.println(gprint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. This question has poor formatting, and there's no tag to specify the language (I assume it's Java). Please [edit] your question, add the tag and fix the indentation. Thank you!

Comment: `grid[i][j] = (char) (Math.random()*('z'-'a'))+'a';`

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't compile for me because your parentheses around Math.random should include 'b', e.g.
`grid[i][j] = (char) (Math.random()*'a'+'b');`
I would also skip storing the individual characters in a string, and just print each character, unless for some reason you needed to do it like that.
`System.out.println(grid[i][j]);`
instead of 
`String gprint = "";
gprint = gprint + String.format("%2c", grid[i][j]);
System.out.println(gprint);`
Finally, if you're specifically trying to have the grid only contain lowercase letters, your formula is a little off. Use
 `Math.random() * ('z' - 'a') + 'a'`
because random will give you a value between 0 and 1, but your desired range is 26 ('z' - 'a'),  not 1, and you want the initial value to be 'a', not 0.